# reference next row and column for vlookup in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I know I need to use Index and Match, but these functions confuse me.

```
Column A     Column B
String       Value
Apple        10
Apple        20
Grape        10
```

*(This is an example, and not the data I'm actually using)*

I'm trying to pull the value of 20 for the second listing of Apple.

Comment: Is column A sorted?  I.e., are all instances of 'Apple' contiguous?

Comment: And in general, are you trying to look up the second instance of something, or the last instance, or just the row below, etc.?  More details please.

Comment: These items are always next to each other.  the first row has the script name and the second row has the script directory.  But they are both titled "Script".  So I'm trying to find in a vlookup way the text script and return the second column for the row beneathe it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the formula that will do it:
=INDEX(B2:B4,MATCH(C2,A2:A4,0)+1)

Your data range is in A2:B4.
In C2 put the value that you want to look up - "Apple".
In D2 copy in the formula from here, it will return 20 from the second "Apple" line.

Comment: Works with the example, but what if the "row below" corresponds to a different "String"? The OP will need to clarify what should be returned if `C2=Grape`